# How to navigate to all invocation of Kotlin invoke() function/operator in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea

I have a class that implements a function:

```
interface Foo : (Int) -> String

class FooImpl: Foo {
   override fun invoke(int: Int) String = TODO()
}
```

Usage:

```
val foo : Foo = FooImpl()
foo() // <-- from here to FooImpl.invoke()?
```

How to find all usages of this special function *invocation* in IntelliJ?

Comment: Yes, regular "find usages" of implicit invoke works.

Comment: @AlexeyBelkov please see the updated question. There is no explicit use of `invoke()`. Also, find usages on `foo()` returns all the places where `foo` is called, not the invoke method.

Comment: Thank you, it doesn't work, please vote for https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTIJ-1050/Go-to-implementation-fails-on-an-override-invoke-function-call-in-both-operator-and-function-forms